# C++ Input stream: operation order in Solaris vs. Linux

Tags: c++, linux, stream, solaris

I have a very simple test program that uses istringstreams to read in integers from a std::string.  The code is:

```
std::map<int, int> imap;
int idx, value;
std::string str("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8");
istringstream is(str);
while(is >> idx >> imap[idx]){
    cout << idx << " " << imap[idx] << endl;
}
cout << endl;

std::map<int, int>::iterator itr;
for(itr = imap.begin(); itr != imap.end(); itr++){
    cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second << endl;
}
```

When I run this on Solaris 10, it produces the following output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8

1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

However, when I run it under CentOS 7, I get:

```
1 0
3 0
5 0
7 0

1 4
3 6
5 8
7 0
4204240 2
```

Does anyone know why it would be different under Linux than under Solaris?  It's obviously reading in the value into the map before reading into the index for the map, but I don't know why.  I can make it work under Linux by changing the code slightly:

```
std::map<int, int> imap;
int idx, value;
std::string str("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8");
istringstream is(str);
while(is >> idx >> value){
    imap[idx] = value;
    cout << idx << " " << imap[idx] << endl;
}

std::map<int, int>::iterator itr;
for(itr = imap.begin(); itr != imap.end(); itr++){
    cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second << endl;
}
```

I know it's a valid fix, but I have people around me who want to know why it is different.  We are migrating from Solaris to Linux and when things like this come up, they want to know why. I don't know why so I'm asking for guidance.

Comment: The fact that it works on one machine and not the other means it is undefined behavior

Comment: Like similar order-of-operations gotchas posted here, the expression `is >> idx >> imap[idx]` evaluates a variable multiple times while modifying it at least once.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
is >> idx >> imap[idx]
```

This expression is equivalent to

```
operator>>(operator>>(is, idx), imap.operator[](idx))
```

The evaluations of arguments to the same function are unsequenced relative to each other; either `operator>>(is, idx)` or `imap.operator[](idx)` may be evaluated first (that is, either `is >> idx` or `imap[idx]` may be evaluated first). If the latter is evaluated first, then the result is an lvalue referring to the value corresponding to the *old* value of `idx` in the map; it is this value that will be overwritten by the second read, and not the value corresponding to the *new* value of `idx`.

The modified code fixes this by ensuring that `idx` is read before `imap[idx]` is accessed.